Return all records that fulfill the criteria in JSON array?
We have JSON data stored in an Azure CosmosDB container like below:
   [
    {
            "WebId": "99999996_2_10_125064",
            "SectionId": 1551,
            "rowtype": 4,
            "Fields": [
                    {
                            "FieldId": 8998,
                            "FieldValue": "1002100481",
                            "FieldName": "<p>Project_No</p>8998"
                    },
                    {
                            "FieldId": 9839,
                            "FieldValue": "Customer Name 123",
                            "FieldName": "<p>Customer_Name</p>9839"
                    }
            ]
    },
    {
            "WebId": "99999996_2_10_125064",
            "SectionId": 1552,
            "rowtype": 4,
            "Fields": [
                    {
                            "FieldId": 13362,
                            "FieldValue": "76215_1_9_122345",
                            "FieldName": "<p>LW_WebID</p>13362"
                    },
                    {
                            "FieldId": 10369,
                            "FieldValue": null,
                            "FieldName": "<p>TRM_ID</p>10369"
                    }
            ]
    }
],
[
    {
            "WebId": "99999996_2_10_125070",
            "SectionId": 1551,
            "rowtype": 4,
            "Fields": [
                    {
                            "FieldId": 8998,
                            "FieldValue": "1002100482",
                            "FieldName": "<p>Project_No</p>8998"
                    },
                    {
                            "FieldId": 9839,
                            "FieldValue": "Customer Name 124",
                            "FieldName": "<p>Customer_Name</p>9839"
                    }
            ]
    },
    {
            "WebId": "99999996_2_10_125070",
            "SectionId": 1552,
            "rowtype": 4,
            "Fields": [
                    {
                            "FieldId": 13362,
                            "FieldValue": "94215_1_9_122346",
                            "FieldName": "<p>LW_WebID</p>13362"
                    },
                    {
                            "FieldId": 10369,
                            "FieldValue": null,
                            "FieldName": "<p>TRM_ID</p>10369"
                    }
            ]
    }
]

Is it possible to get all WebIDs where the FieldValue for Fields.FieldName = <p>LW_WebID</p>13362 is Fields.FieldValue LIKE '76215_1_9_%'? From the sample data, it should only get the records from WebId = '99999996_2_10_125064'.
Currently, we are only able to pull all records that have the Field.FieldId values 8998, 9839, 13362 and 10369 like below. Afterwards, we pivot the data in Power Query and filter the LW_WebId but is it possible filter the data directly via the native query?
    SELECT
    c["WebId"]
    , c["SectionId"]
    , c["rowtype"]
    , d["FieldId"]
    , d["FieldName"]
    , d["FieldValue"]
FROM c
JOIN d IN c["Fields"]
WHERE
    c["WebId"] LIKE '99999996_2_10_%'
    d["FieldId"] IN (13362, 8998, 9839)


Try with the below query it gets the record with WebId = '99999996_2_10_125064' by following respective conditions as shown below:
SELECT
    c["WebId"]
    , c["SectionId"]
    , c["rowtype"]
    , d["FieldId"]
    , d["FieldName"]
    , d["FieldValue"]
FROM c
JOIN d IN c["Fields"]
WHERE
    c["WebId"] LIKE '99999996_2_10_%'
    AND (
        d["FieldName"] = '<p>LW_WebID</p>13362' AND STARTSWITH(d["FieldValue"], '76215_1_9_')
    )

Output:
[
    {
        "WebId": "99999996_2_10_125064",
        "SectionId": 1552,
        "rowtype": 4,
        "FieldId": 13362,
        "FieldName": "<p>LW_WebID</p>13362",
        "FieldValue": "76215_1_9_122345"
    }
]


This only gets the records with the d["FieldName"] = '<p>LW_WebID</p>13362', whose FieldID = 13362. We also need the entries where the FieldId is 8998 or 9839. Is this not actually possible?
